# Implement Skype call and chat API on my PHP website

Tags: php, skype

I have a website, the programming language I used is PHP.
I want to implement Skype API to the website for voice call and chat.
Please help me guys.
If you have any sample code that is best for me.
Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO friend! Do you have any code or are you looking for someone to give you a tutorial? The latter is not done on here, there are websites for that, SO is all about helping people fix problems, not make the thing for them :)

Comment: Looking for sample code? Try github

Comment: try NetTuts, http://tutsplus.com/tutorials/ short for interNet Tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call someone on Skype and you have their username use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_yourskypename_1">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 Skype.ui({
 "name": "call",
 "element": "SkypeButton_Call_yourskypename_1",
 "participants": ["yourskypename"],
 "imageSize": 32
 });
 </script>
</div>
```

I believe you cannot use chat functionality thought...

More info at http://www.skype.com/en/developer/